# Cannot use find.where() in Ebean Model

Tags: playframework, ebean

I'm trying to use an Ebean finder inside of a model. When I try to do find.where() it errors saying it cannot resolve the method.

Model Code:

```
package models;

import io.ebean.Finder;
import io.ebean.Model;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class TestModel extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @Column(length = 256, unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(256)
    @Constraints.Required
    private String testField;


    public static final Finder<Long, TestModel> find = new Finder<>(TestModel.class);

    public void testFunction() {
        find.where() // Error: Cannot resolve method where()
    }
}
```

Edit: Like examples on [this page](https://ebean.io/docs/getting-started/java-finder)

I've tried different formats and structures from other posts. Also tried creating a TestModelFinder extending Finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [source code](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/blob/master/src/main/java/io/ebean/Finder.java) I don't think that Finder has such method. You should implement it by yourself like [documentation says](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/blob/master/src/main/java/io/ebean/Finder.java#L33)